# Outlook Windows Notification: Change UX, Group by Sender with Icon

Tags: outlook, push-notification, notifications, windows-10

Is there any way to design Outlook Notifications? Perhaps Group and Cluster them by Sender? Or perhaps add an Icon?

Generally, is there a way to set the UX for Outlook notifications?

We have 10000 customers, and we want to change their UX  notifications in lower right.

[image]